# vba excel comparing date values

Tags: excel, vba

EXCELVBA

My column A has a list of dates, in date order.  I need to compare each date in turn e.g. date value in cell A2 is equal or not to date value in cell A3, if equal then compare cell A3 with A4, re-iterate until the date in the next row cell does not equal the cell previous.  I would then like to add a row and a text value in the NEW row cell column A.

I'm trying to work this out for myself but would appreciate pointing in the right direction

Comment: Please include the code you are using to solve this in your question and explain what specific problems you are having with it.

Comment: Also, what happens when you found the first cell that's not equal to `A2`, would your iteration stop? You are leaving a lot of quessing work for people who would want to help you. Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly

Comment: I need to continue checking dates after the new row, until the dates are not equal then add another row with text in new row.